# Question about notation for defining homotopies

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

I'm looking at this part of a statement regarding homotopic paths:

> Given homotopies $$h: f \simeq f' : X \rightarrow Y, k: g \simeq g' : Y \rightarrow Z$$

Now here I'm a bit confused of whether $h$ and $k$ are maps into different topological spaces or does that part of the notation refer to the maps $f$ and $f'$? In other words, is the interpretation $f: X \rightarrow Y$ or $h: X \rightarrow Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ and $f'$ are maps $X \longrightarrow Y$. $g$ and $g'$ are maps $Y \longrightarrow Z$. $h$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $f'$, so $h: X \times [0, 1] \longrightarrow Y$ such that $h(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $h(x, 1) = f'(x)$ or vice versa. Similarly, $k$ is a homotopy between $g$ and $g'$ so it is a map $Y \times [0, 1] \longrightarrow Z$ such that $k(y, 0) = g(y)$ and $k(y, 1) = g'(y)$ or vice versa.